# how can i get the session in websocket in tomcat7

Tags: session, websocket

Here I use Tomcat7 as server. And I set the session in:

```
http:/localhost:8080//Chat/login.action
```

So how can I get that session in:

```
ws://127.0.0.1:8080/Chat/chat.ws
```

Because I want every one login in before they go to the chat page. And what I need is their username which I decide to use in chat page when they submit in `login.action`